# Must you set references to null for garbage collection to work

Tags: java, memory, jvm

Hi i am attempting to discover why my program's usually run slower than i want them so thank you in advance for your help!

---

I have for example a piece of code that i would like some insight into

```
1. while(conditionIsTrue){
2.      Object object = new Object();
3.  }
```

in Line #2. I create a new Object. This will happen thousands of times in my program. Do i specifically have to `null` the old Object out before gc will destroy it? Or will gc go behind my program picking up all the memory those other Objects used.

Or another option altogether is this happening: A certain amount of memory is being allocated and every time i create a new Object it is then assigned to that exact same memory.

---

Bruno asked me to show a more realistic piece of code so we could figure out why it was running slowly. But, because of your answer Bruno i realized that i had my code like this

```
1. Object object = null;
2. while(conditionIsTrue){
3.      object = new Object();
4.  }
```

So i realized i had Strong references to my Objects. Thank you Bruno!

Comment: No, you do not need to null out the old pointer.  And there really is no significant difference between your first and second code snippets, from a performance standpoint.  (There is no "strong reference" distinction in Java.)

Comment: @HotLicks, what exactly do you mean by *There is no "strong reference" distinction in Java*? There are lots of distinct types of reference, including strong, soft, weak, phantom, each with very particular characteristics on how they interact with the GC.

Comment: "usually runs slower than I want to" is normal. Every computer program always runs slower than you'd like to. And then you upgrade your hardware and think WOW for 5 minutes before it again starts to feel like it's slowing down even when it isn't. Microoptimalisation isn't going to change that, and that's what you're attempting here.

Comment: @BrunoReis - There are different Reference object types, true, but ordinary pointers are not "strong" or "weak", unlike some C-based GC schemes.  You don't normally get a Reference object created unless you do something explicit to cause it, and there are few things a naive Java programmer can do to cause it.

Comment: @jwenting I understand that for small programs micro-optimization doesn't create a huge difference. But for a program that has well over 100k lines of code it does. But thank you for your input.

Comment: @snocavotia you're wrong. It MAY make a difference in any program, IF it accidentally hits something that gets called a lot, but size of the program is no indication whether that will happen or not.  In fact, in a 100k line program the chance of one single thing like this making a noticeable difference in percentages of CPU time or memory used are far smaller than in a 100 line program, which is why so many people think microoptimisation is useful, they only ever tried in small programs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to `object = null;` to allow the GC to clear the `new Object()`, since there are no references left to the object right after the iteration that instantiated the object finishes (that is, line #3).

The rule is: the GC is allowed to clear an object whenever there are no more *[strong references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ref/package-summary.html)* pointing to it. It might not clear the object right away, it might take some time, but unless you manage to acquire new strong references to it (yes, there are ways! see [`SoftReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) and [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) for example), it will eventually be cleared, and certainly before it throws an [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).

Also, the JVM is very smart about allocating memory. There's something called *[escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis)*: it allows the JVM to understand that the `new Object()` is not used anywhere outside that loop, so it may even allocate the memory for the object right *on the stack*, not on the heap! Therefore, it might be the case that no GC is needed at all for that specific object -- when the method finishes, the object is automatically cleared.

I would even guess that the JVM might detect that instantiating that object has absolutely no noticeable effect at all, and might even simply chose not to run that line #2 (but this is a guess, and an optimization I might think about doing if I were writing a compiler -- if someone knows for sure if this happens or does not happen, please add a comment!).

If your program is running slower than *you'd like it run*, then you'd have to show some more realistic code. Something that you might consider a *subtle* difference between your real code and the snippet you asked about might be a huge difference for the JVM!

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me so much! I'll definitely be cleaning up some of my old "sloppy" programming habits.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be also helpful to know that you can use a tool like [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) to see how your program uses memory, threads and more.

VisualVM is bundled with JDK since version 6 update 7 and you can find it in JDK_HOME/bin